# Two way synch from Desktop to (ReadyNas) network drive

Tags: samba, sync, rsync, file-sharing, nas

I am trying to make my documents folder synchronise with my ReadyNas network drive.

Currently, I am already synchronising my Windows Laptop's Documents folder with the network drive on my ReadyNas via Window Sync Centre.  Is there anything similar to Window Sync Centre/Off-line files for Ubuntu which I can use to synchronise the documents folder on my Ubuntu machine with the network drive, allowing me to have the same documents files on my Windows and Linux machines.

Summery:

What I am looking for is something similar to Windows Off-line files / a way to synchronise my Ubuntu computer and Window Laptop via my (SAMBA) network drive.

This means that when I make change on a file on my Ubuntu Desktop, it will automatically synchronise the change when it next connects to the ReadyNas, meaning it will send & receive all changes since it was last connected to the network Drive.

Comment: is it not possible to mount the NAS in fstab and thus, when the file is saved to the NAS (as opposed to a local linux folder), the current version is immediately available or have I misunderstood your requirement?

Comment: @24601 I want to have the NAS mounted as the Documents folder, and have it available when I am not connected to the Wi-Fi.

If I mounted it via fstab it would leave me without a Documents folder when I do not have Wi-Fi.